# Remove Alphabets only from a H-Column - MS Excel 2007 (Without Plugin)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to remove all the alphabets from a column in one go. I want only the numbers to be remaining. there are 6000 cells and its difficult to delete text one by one. is it possible?

```
Current Column
[text 123456]
[text 123456]
[text 123456]
and so on...
```

What I want

```
[123456]
[123456]
[123456]
and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on any cell in the column of interest and run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, v As String, CH As String
    Dim v2 As String
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            v2 = ""
            l = Len(v)
            For i = 1 To l
                CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
                If IsNumeric(CH) Then
                    v2 = v2 & CH
                End If
            Next i
            r.Value = v2
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#2:**

To **remove** numbers, replace:

```
If IsNumeric(CH) Then
```

with:

```
If Not IsNumeric(CH) Then
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use `macro` ? :)

Comment: And if I want to remove Numbers instead of Alphabets?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and if I want to remove `numbers`?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use a formula which you can <kbd>copy</kbd> + <kbd>paste</kbd> down your column of data (example is for column A):

```
="["&MID(A1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)),"",FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)))+1,FIND("]",A1,1))
```

Here is a visual example:

[image]